# Bouncy Castle DSA with SHA1 signature verification

Tags: java, cryptography, digital-signature, bouncycastle

My project is using signature verification of some datasets which come from certain third-party software. Signature algorithm used is `SHA1withDSA`. When I was using standard SUN crypto provider, that comes with SDK, all went fine. Recently I switched to Bouncy Castle 1.50, and after that some of datasets which previously (that is, with SUN
provider) stood verification, began to fail it, while the rest is still verified OK.

I explored source codes of both providers, and it turned out that SDK's default provider has some sort of protection from incorrectly formed signatures (while capable of being recovered), and Bouncy Castle provider does not have it. Check out
[OpenJDK
for Java 7](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u/jdk/file/8fe3cb32ff83/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/DSA.java) (lines 336-344) or
[OpenJDK
for Java 8](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/4edaec5f08c0/src/share/classes/sun/security/provider/DSA.java) (lines 265-273): there they have made some signature fix in certain case. Whereas there is no such thing done for `org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.dsa.DSASigner#engineVerify`, moreover, in `org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.DSASigner#verifySignature` it is explicitly stated that numbers must be positive, otherwise verification fails straight away.

Is it a bug in BC, or is there something that I missed? To overcome
this, I have subclassed `org.bouncycastle.crypto.signers.DSASigner` and
added there the same aforementioned signature fix, then plugged this
in as yet another signature algorithm (through subclassing `org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.dsa.DSASigner`). But maybe there is another way that I overlooked, and this "issue" is well-known? Please advise.

Comment: *Is it a bug in BC, or is there something that I missed* - It is not a bug in BC. After all the comments in the code you point to mentions that that the values are incorrectly encoded, and not accepting incorrectly encoded information hardly can count as a bug. Quite the contrary, *accepting* malformed signatures or certificates is quite questionable because it might impose security threats.

Comment: @mkl, you can't fix third-party software which fails to encode ASN.1 integers properly, but [you can read and process such data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle). Of course, deciding whether to reject an input outright or whether to enable lax processing to fix the common mistake in other software is a tough question.

Comment: @OlegEstekhin *deciding ... is a tough question* - Yes, it is. And especially in case of security related incorrect input "reading and processing" the input may be a bad idea as it may undermine security features. That been said I'm very aware that customer pressure can force you to "read and process" even if you see security aspects weakened that way.

Comment: @mkl The problem I see it is once I am using crypto facilities in a unified way, that is, through JCA, then switching providers might be accompanied with minor distinctions in behavior, but not that drastic. And personally I take JDK's default implementation as a quite thoroughly thought out piece of software. If they hadn't dropped support of SHA1withDSA1 for long keys, I would never have switched to BC. But at least they have some plausible [justification](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8039921) for this, about being legacy and that. But OK, I think I can live with my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the incorrect BER/DER encoding of ASN.1 integers - which are stored as **signed** big endian, right aligned octets - is indeed the culprit then Bouncy does **not** have a bug. Positive values should be left padded with a `00` valued byte if the first bit of the encoding is set, otherwise it would represent a negative value.

The Sun provider is wrong to allow those kind of signatures to verify, and the other party is of course generating invalid signatures. Note that it is possible to let the signatures verify without this "fix" within the Sun code: simply adjust the encoding *before* feeding it to the verification function.

The only time when this is not possible is when the DSA verification is called as a generic signature verification method from another library instead of from an application that can adjust the data before the call.

On the other hand, I think you've created an elegant fix. The only issue with it is that it may not run if the provider's signature is verified from a JCA compliant framework. The other possible fix is to re-encode *before* feeding it into the `Signature` class for verification.

Note that I don't see how this could be a security issue; the signature consists of the values of R and S, and it does not matter how they are encoded, as long as you receive the correct values in the end.

Comment: OK, thank you, I think I'll go with my solution then.